# Метод erase из vector<string> не принимает параметр string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В этом отрывке кода не компилируется erase

```
int countDel = 0;
    for (auto item : Events) {
        for (const string i : item.second) {
            if (predicate(item.first, i)) {
                item.second.erase(i);
                countDel++;
            }
        }
    }
return countDel;
```

predicate - функция, возвращающая bool

В ошибке пишет:

> отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "std::vector<_Ty,
>   _Alloc>::erase [с _Ty=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator]", соответствующие списку аргументов

Весь день вчера ломал над эти голову, но к выводу так и не пришел

P.s: Events - `map<***, vector<string>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) у ветора принимает либо позицию, либо итератор, либо диапазон. Чем из них, по-вашему, является строка? :)

Да и, кстати, `item` у вас - копия, а не ссылка - так что толку от удаления, буде даже оно выполнялось бы - никакого. Тогда уж используйте `for(auto& item : Events)`..

Comment: Блин, и правда. В Events до этого set стоял, в не вектор, и я запутался в методах. Спасибо :)

Comment: @Vakarine: Это совершенно не важно, был ли там set или что-то еще.  Код неработоспособен и с set тоже.

Answer (score 1):

При использовании range-based for в общем случае не позволяется удалять элементы из того контейнера, по которому производится итерирование. Range-based for не предназначен для таких применений.

Ваш код, по-видимому, пытается удалить текущий итерируемый элемент, что в любом случае приведет к инвалидации внутреннего итератора range-based for. Это - сразу неопределенное поведение. Поэтому независимо от того, что там у вас за контейнер используется, по ссылке ли, по значению ли, и допускает ли он удаление по значению элемента - все это не важно. Ваш код неработоспособен уже из-за использования range-based for.

Не пытаетесь использовать range-based for там, где он неуместен.

Comment: Я там сделал через for криворуко, ибо по-другому пока не знаю как, хотя, думаю, надо попытаться алгоритм remove?